# How can I do a piechart so i can click on any slice?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, pie-chart

I don't know how to do a circle divided into 12 pieces ( slices) so I can click on one of them. I want to do this in matlab. I think is like  radio buttons, but i dont know how to make this shape i want.

It's like an pie chart (equaly divided) and I can click on a slice like on a button. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

The output of `pie` is an array of handles to the patches and text labels that make up the pie chart. You can set the `ButtonDownFcn` of the patch objects to capture the mouse click. You could then compare the handle of the clicked patch with your array of patches to figure out which one was clicked.

Here is an example:

```
handles = pie(1:5);
patches = findall(handles, 'type', 'patch');

set(patches, 'ButtonDownFcn', @(s,e)clickfunction(find(patches == s)))

function clickfunction(index)
    fprintf('Clicked piece: %d\n', index)
end
```

[image]

Comment: How did you make the nice gif?

Comment: @BeniaminIonutDobre This is just a reminder that you can mark the answer as accepted if it solved your question